# Vue js filter don't work when space is pressed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a filter which returns array based on the first name and last name. I made it case insensetive. But the problem is when I press a space it doesn't return any result.For example let's say the name is (including first name and last name) `Sadek Hossain`. Now if I search for `sadek` it works but if I type `sadek hossain` or `Sadek Hossain` it never works. As soon as a space is pressed it doesn't work.

Here is the filter code I am using.

```
filterUser(){
            return this.buddylist.filter((buddy)=>{
                return buddy.oponent.firstName.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) || buddy.oponent.lastName.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase());
            })
        }
```

Comment: Because 'sadek hossain' doesn't match either of your conditions. You're testing whether 'sadek hossain' is the first name or 'sadek hossain' is the last name.

Comment: Yeah I am also thinking so :( Is there any ways to escape space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match the full name you should check against the first + last with something like:

```
filterUser(){
   return this.buddylist.filter((buddy)=>{
     var fullname = buddy.oponent.firstName.trim() + " " + buddy.oponent.lastName.trim()
     return fullname.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/\s+/g,' '))

   })
}
```

This replaces extra spaces in the user input with one space. Strips any extra space off first and last name. Concatenates the first + last and compares.

If you want to match first name or last name or full name you'll need to combine this with your previous function.

Comment: Thank you. I also though same way but you made my life easy. :) Thank you so much. Here is the code if some else needs helps :) 

`filterUser(){
    return this.buddylist.filter((buddy)=>{
     var fullname = buddy.oponent.firstName.trim() + " " + buddy.oponent.lastName.trim();
     return buddy.oponent.firstName.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) || buddy.oponent.lastName.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) || fullname.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,' '))
    })
   }`